# Send playable video to discord with JDA

Tags: video, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to send a video in a discord channel using JDA but when I send a video it shows up like this :

[image: Wrong video format]

and I want it to show up like this :

[image: Correct video format]

Basically I'd like to make the video playable in discord when the Bot uploads it. Does anyone know a way to do this? I've tried uploading it from an InputStream and from a local file but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it the correct file extension. Calling it `video.mp4` instead of just `video` should work.